# Python: Using Regex to create an array of non-duplicate entries

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I am writing a function to find the names of processes occurring on a system. I take in an array like this:

```
['\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(python)\\Operations/sec',
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process#2)\\Operations/sec', 
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process#1)\\Operations/sec', 
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process)\\Operations/sec', 
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(python)\\Thread Count', 
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process#2)\\Thread Count',
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process#1)\\Thread Count',
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process)\\Thread Count'....etc....]
```

and I want to output the names of each process in an array like this:

```
['python','process#2','process#1','process']
```

(Note that if a process come up more than once in the original array I do not want duplicates in the ouput array)

Here is what I have so far:

```
def count_no_of_processes(row_to_check):
    #Ignore first entry
    to_search= row_to_check[1:]
    processes=[]
    for number in range(0,len(header_to_search)):
        search = re.search(r"\(([^)]+)\)", header_to_search[number])
        processes.append(search
    print processes
```

But this doesn't give me the a list of processes it just says `"<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10c1fw321>"` within the `"processes"` list.

What am I doing wrong?

I have yet to get to the stage or checking for duplications in the `processes` list but if any has any advice it would be appreciated as I am new to using Regex .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could come up with:

```
import re

processes = ['\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(python)\\Operations/sec',
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process#2)\\Operations/sec', 
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process#1)\\Operations/sec', 
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process)\\Operations/sec', 
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(python)\\Thread Count', 
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process#2)\\Thread Count',
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process#1)\\Thread Count',
'\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process)\\Thread Count']

rx = re.compile(r'Process\(([^)]+)\)')

processes_filtered = []
for process in processes:
    match = rx.search(process)
    if match is not None:
        if match.group(1) not in processes_filtered:
            processes_filtered.append(match.group(1))

print processes_filtered
# ['python', 'process#2', 'process#1', 'process']
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/3yw8Ef).

Or - even shorter - with a **list comprehension**:

```
rx = re.compile(r'Process\(([^)]+)\)')
processes_filtered = set([m.group(1) \
    for process in processes \
    for m in [rx.search(process)] if m])
```

Answer (score 1):

Reminder that [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) returns a MatchObject; in order to extract what you want, you would want to use something like `match.group(1)` which would return the first group of the match, in other words, the tokens inside of your `()` capturing group in your regex.

Note that you should do a check if you indeed did catch a match before you call `.group` since `re.search` will return `None` if it doesn't match and calling `None.group` will raise an error.

To address your secondary question about duplicates, I suggest using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Answer (score 0):

If order does not matter, you can do:

```
>>> import re
>>> tgt=['\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(python)\\Operations/sec',
... '\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process#2)\\Operations/sec', 
... '\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process#1)\\Operations/sec', 
... '\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process)\\Operations/sec', 
... '\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(python)\\Thread Count', 
... '\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process#2)\\Thread Count',
... '\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process#1)\\Thread Count',
... '\\\\TEST-PC\\Process(process)\\Thread Count']
>>> {m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r'^[^(]+\(([^)]+)\)', '\n'.join(tgt), flags=re.M)}
set(['python', 'process#2', 'process#1', 'process'])
```